# Active admin column with do and without do are they same in performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

```
column 'Name' do |c|
   c.name
 end
```

```
 column :name
```

Are they same in execution time and performance wise ?
Any of them is good for better performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one, with a `block` will be slightly slower, as an extra `yield` will be performed at the call-site. I doubt you will notice the difference, and/or that when profiled it will show speed-gains.